# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT while reaching Tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have VM (Ubuntu 20.4, Tomcat9) running on Google Cloud that is connected through VPN IkeV2 to our LAN. I can't access the service through web browser via 10.x.x.x:8080, returning "Err_connection_timed_out" despite having installed and correctly configured it. If I connect via remote desktop to the VM, I can see the status page stating Tomcat is running fine. I opened all the necessary ports in the Google Cloud, but I cannot sort out this problem.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your LAN infrastructure know how to route to that IP address space?  Can you ping that IP?

Comment: @DigantCKasundra Yes, I can ping it from our LAN

Answer (score 1):

- Confirm if port 8080 is configured on GCE's firewall and tomcat is
  listening on the correct port. Run the netstat command to check the
  listening port.

  ```
                         netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
  ```
- Check if port 8080 is accessible from outside. Port could be blocked.
  Check your firewall settings and open the port for http request.
- Also it could be that Tomcat is only listening on the localhost. You
  might need to set the [HTTP-Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) address attribute to your IP
  address so that Tomcat listens on it. To make Tomcat listen on the
  10.x.x.x  address, add ‘address=10.x.x.x’ in the Connector string of the tomcat9/server.xml file and restart the tomcat server after
  changes are done. It looks something like:

  ```
                        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
                        maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" 
                        connectionTimeout="20000" 
                        redirectPort="8443" 
                        address="IP address" />
  ```
- Confirm if you have enabled the  "Allow HTTP traffic" checkbox in VM
  configuration.

Comment: Thank you Prya, I already tried all these steps, but the situation won't change.

Comment: @Fabio T, Are you able to resolve localhost using curl http://localhost:8080/? Have you tried it using **address="0.0.0.0"** or **useIPVHosts=”true”** under the connector string in the server.xml file? Also share the supporting tomcat logs and server.xml file config to check further. Run the command ‘sudo nmap -sTU -O <IP address>’ to check which port is open.